# How to set DefaultFont to custom font in OxyPlot?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I am using *OxyPlot* in a WPF application to plot a simple `LineSeries`. I also defined *Roboto* as the standard font of my application. However my `PlotView` does not use this font but uses its default font *Segoe UI*.

The `PlotModel` offers a `DefaultFont` property to change this font. This property does not accept a `FontFamily` but only a string. So if I try to modify the font by entering a `FontFamily` name which is installed on my system it works:

```
var model = new PlotModel
{
     DefaultFont = "Verdana"
};
```

If I try to do the same with *Roboto* it does not:

```
var model = new PlotModel
{
     DefaultFont = "./Resources/Roboto/#Roboto"
};
```

or

```
var model = new PlotModel
{
     DefaultFont = "/MyNamespace;component/Resources/Roboto/#Roboto"
};
```

What am I missing here? Is there maybe another way to accomplish this?

**Note:** This is my first question, please tell me what I can improve in the future.

Comment: I am fairly new to the whole OxyPlot thema, but maybe you can define the Font into the `Window/UserControl.Resources`? Maybe then will PlotModel find the Font?

Comment: @Jonas did you manage to get this work?